# Cordova Electron Ionic project does not show Ionic contents

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, electron

I am just investigating my options for replacing Windows/UWP in my Ionic/Cordova project. Electron seem to be what I need

To test, I create a new blank  Ionic project (eg Tabs), made sure it run (Ionic serve), and then followed instructions [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/electron/)

I did the `ionic cordova platform add cordova-electron` and then `cordova build electron` and it seem to build and I ended up with an exe in `D:\dev\ionic\electron-ionic\platforms\electron\build`

This launches, and has an unwanted menu (will look into that later), but the first concern is the html contents are blank - it has not included the Ionic app at all...

[image]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 2 stupid mistakes

- As for all Windows apps, index.html needs `<base href="./" />` instead of `<base href="/" />` (ie the the dot)
- I of course need to first build ionic app

`ionic build`

After this, it worked.